# UILabel - iOS 14 some words are going to new line as compare to iOS 13

Tags: ios13, ios14, typography

I have observed one issue where UILabel's text is going into a new line in iOS 14 and it looks different for iOS 13. I checked if there are any changes in the font or typography in iOS 14 but didn't find anything which can clearly tell what caused that issue.

**iOS 14:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfmXF.png]

**iOS 13**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOZom.png]

Note: I am using the same simulator device iPad 9.7 inch. Autolayout constraints and every setting are the same.

Comment: Are you using SwiftUI or UIKit? Can you share the label configurations and it superview configurations, and the name of font? It seems some kind of font did change between the version (unofficial source - a related bug on flutter form https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60013)

Comment: I am using UIKit. Everything is same. Superview is main view of the viewcontroller.

Comment: This is controlled by the new `lineBreakStrategy`.